# Validate a string (1-3 numbers split by /) using a regular expression

Tags: regex

I need to validate a string using a regular expression.

The valid string should have 1-3 numbers split by / character

For example

- **12/24/60/90 -> valid**
- 12//23/546/4 -> invalid
- /33/324 -> invalid
- //32 -> invalid
- // -> invalid
- / -> invalid
- **4/23/234 -> valid**
- 12/21////3//////4///45656 -> invalid

The regex I was able to figure out is

```
^(\d{1,3}\/(?!\/))(.*$)
```

Unfortunately, this regular expression is not perfect. It evaluates the last string from the example as a valid one.

I need to modify the current RegEx or prepare a different, but correct expression.

UPD:

**This regular expression works perfectly**

```
^\d{1,3}(?:\/\d{1,3})*$
```

Comment: Most practical IMO would be `^\d{1,3}(?:\/\d{1,3})*$`

Comment: @JvdV Thanks to much! It works perfectly

Comment: @JvdV: Additionally, a demo: https://regex101.com/r/VIjGyv/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regular expression works perfectly

```
^\d{1,3}(?:\/\d{1,3})*$
```

Thanks to @JvdV!